# Issue smoothing map borders with ggplot2 and RMapShaper

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps

I am trying to create a map with smooth borders using `geom_polygon()` and `ms_simplify()`, using the shapefile in [this link](https://github.com/LucasTremlett/Proyecto-Visualizacion/blob/master/georef-spain-comunidad-autonoma-millesime.shp). When I create the map without `ms_simplify()` the output comes out correctly (Image 1), however when I use `ms_simplify()` to smoothen the borders, I get the following warning: `"In sp::proj4string(sp) : CRS object has comment, which is lost in output"`, and the borders of the output that follows are completely messed up, as can be seen in Image 2.

**Image 1**

[image]

**Image 2**

[image]

Why does this  problem happen, and how can it be solved? Here is the code I used for the map:

```
shapefile<-readOGR(
  dsn = "/georef-spain-comunidad-autonoma-millesime.shp") ##Descargar en https://public.opendatasoft.com/explore/dataset/comunidades-autonomas-espanolas/export/?sort=comunidade_autonoma

shapefile<-rmapshaper::ms_simplify(shapefile, keep = 0.01, keep_shapes = T) 
nombres <- tibble(shapefile$acom_name) %>% 
  mutate(id = as.character(seq(0, nrow(.)-1))) %>% mutate(codigo=shapefile$acom_code) 
mapa <- tidy(shapefile)
mapa<- mapa %>% left_join(nombres, by=c("id"="id")) %>% 
  rename("nombre"="shapefile$acom_name") %>% mutate(codigo=as.numeric(codigo))

mapa <- mapa %>% mutate(lat1=case_when(codigo==5 ~ lat + 7.8,
                                     codigo!=5 ~ lat),
                      long1=case_when(codigo==5 ~ long + 6.35,
                                      codigo!=5 ~ long),
                      codigo=as.numeric(codigo)) %>% filter(codigo<=17)
datos.estudio<- data.frame(codigo=c(1:17),
                  porc=c(16, 3, 3,
                         4, 6, 1,
                         5, 3, 18,
                         11, 3, 5,
                         17, 4, 2,
                         6, 1
                    ))
mapa <- mapa %>% left_join(datos.estudio, by=c("codigo"="codigo"))
texto.mapa<- mapa %>% group_by(nombre, porc) %>% summarise(long=mean(long1), lat=mean(lat1)) 

mapa %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_polygon(aes(x= long1, y = lat1,group=group, fill=porc),
               color="white") + coord_equal() + 
  geom_text(aes(x=long, y=lat,label=paste0(porc,"%")), 
            data=texto.mapa, size=3.25) +
  geom_rect(xmin=-12, xmax=-7, ymin=35.4, ymax=37.1, color="black", alpha=0,
            size=1.25) +
  theme_void() + 
  theme(legend.position = "none") + 
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "grey", high = "darkred")
```

Comment: FYI, for inline code (in the middle of words) you can use a single backtick, not 3 backticks.

Comment: I would use `sf::st_simplify`, but that needs an sf object (sf is the newer r spatial data package)